# How Can I Monitor SQL service with Zabbix?

Tags: sql-server-2014

We are implementing Zabbix, monitoring a lot of processes.

But I think it would be great to monitor the SQL service ( if it's running, stopped...)

[image]

We are now monitoring Ping, conections services and etc.

[image]

im new in this Area, But it's something I was asked to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor status of any Windows service with a Windows-specific item key (when using Zabbix agent) `service.info`.

See [Windows-specific agent key documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys) for more detail.